# square brackets in query parameter keys

Tags: javascript, axios, get

I need to GET data from an API that uses square brackets as part of the parameter name. I didn't write the API, so don't shoot the messenger!

Edit: I should have noted, this code will run on node (server-side), not in the browser.

I'm using Axios in Javascript, and this is my axios call:

```
axios.get(url, {params: {queryParams}})
    .then(res => {
        brands = res.data;
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log( '\n\n\n\n')
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The params are as follows. For brevity, I'm showing the three different formats I've tried (direct character, escaped and ASCII encoded), but in each attempt, I've passed the three parameters with the same format.

```
Set the query parameters
let queryParams = {
    "tables": table,
    "manifest": manifest,
    "where[0][0]": field,
    "where%5B0%5D%5B1%5D": "%3D",
    "where\\[0\\]\\[2\\]": searchValue,
    "ordery_by": "id%2C%20ASC",
    "limit": "100",
    "app": "json",
    'client_key': authkey
}
```

In all cases, axios seems to transform the parameters into a javascript web token.

If, on the other hand, I concatenate the parameters to the URL as a string, the request works, and I get the data I expected.

```
let fullPath = url.concat(
    "?tables=", table,
    "&manifest=", manifest,
    "&where%5B0%5D%5B0%5D=", field,
    "&where%5B0%5D%5B1%5D=", "%3D",
    "&where%5B0%5D%5B2%5D=", searchValue,
    "&ordery_by=", "id%2C%20ASC",
    "&limit=", "100",
    "&app=", "json",
    "&client_key=", authkey
)
```

While I have a workaround solution (as shown above), is there a way doing this with a proper parameters object?

Comment: Axios will not encode square brackets and are explicitly ignored. There is a PR, but it has not been merged in yet. github.com/axios/axios/issues/3316

Comment: *axios seems to transform the parameters into a javascript web token* - this is probably a typo and means JSON Web token (you also added the JWT tag). But still, what does all this have to do with JWT? Did you actually simply mean something like "... transform the parameters into JSON"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in browser you could use the [URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to iterate a human readable object and have it create the query string.

There is also a similar module available for Node

axios supports passing a [URLSearchParams object as params argument](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#browser) also

```js
let queryParams = {
    "tables": 1,
    "manifest": 2,
    "where[0][0]": 3,
    "where[0][1]": "=",
    "where[0][2]": 4,
    "ordery_by": "id,ASC",
    "limit": "100",
    "app": "json",
    'client_key': 'abc'
}

const sParams = new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(queryParams));

console.log('query string')
console.log(sParams.toString())
console.log('sParam entries')
console.log(JSON.stringify([...sParams]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {   max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```

Going a step further you can construct the full url with URL constructor

```
const url = new URL('https://myApi.com')
url.search = new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(queryParams));

console.log(url.href)
```

Comment: I have not had the time to try these options, but I will do so in the next few days. Thank you!

Comment: I have had the time to try using URLSearchParams and using the URL constructor and it still failed in the same way. It's very strange.

Comment: Axios will not encode square brackets and are explicitly ignored. There is a PR, but it has not been merged in yet. https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3316

Answer (score 0):

One work around could be like:

```
myParams = new URLSearchParams();
myParams.append("filter[number]", "mynumber");
myParams.append("filter[id]", "someId");
const searchQueryParams = decodeURIComponent(mySearchParams.toString());
console.log(searchQueryParams);
```

The console log should show:

```
'filter[number]=mynumber&filter[id]=someId'
```